# How to fix non passive element issue of chrome for jquery 1.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a project where we used jquery 1.x with dataTables functionality. This functionality seems to work fine for firefox browser but for chrome its not working and nor giving any error in console. Its just giving warning of

> Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking
>   'touchmove'/'touchstart' event. Consider marking event handler as
>   'passive' to make the page more responsive.

I tried some of the solutions like adding `preventDefault()` or adding script to passive false but it didn't work out.

like

```
jQuery.event.special.touchstart = {
  setup: function( _, ns, handle ){
   if ( ns.includes("noPreventDefault") ) {
     this.addEventListener("touchstart", handle, { passive: false });
   } else {
     this.addEventListener("touchstart", handle, { passive: true });
  }
 }
};
jQuery.event.special.touchmove = {
   setup: function( _, ns, handle ){
      if ( ns.includes("noPreventDefault") ) {
         this.addEventListener("touchmove ", handle, { passive: false });
      } else {
         this.addEventListener("touchmove ", handle, { passive: true });
      }
   }
};
```

Is this related to jquery versioning. If yes, so does I need to migrate it for datatable (Its suppourted in Firefox though right now).

Answer (score 0):

I created a package that adds `passive` attribute with a proper value depending of a `preventDefault` usage. See [passive-events-support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passive-events-support)

Give it a try and make sure to pass only the events that cause the warning:

```
<script>
  window.passiveEvents = ['touchstart', 'touchmove']
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/passive-events-support/dist/main.js"></script>
```

This fixed the `jquery` issue on my end.

Answer (score -1):

```
can you please try with

jQuery.event.special.touchstart = {
  setup: function( _, ns, handle ){
   if ( ns.includes("noPreventDefault") ) {
     this.addEventListener("touchstart", handle, { passive: false });
   } else {
     this.addEventListener("touchstart", handle, { passive: false }); // updated here
  }
 }
};
jQuery.event.special.touchmove = {
   setup: function( _, ns, handle ){
      if ( ns.includes("noPreventDefault") ) {
         this.addEventListener("touchmove ", handle, { passive: false });
      } else {
         this.addEventListener("touchmove ", handle, { passive: false }); // updated here
      }
   }
};
```

Comment: 1. What's the point of `if else`? 2. This will remove the warning, but will not improve scrolling performance...

Answer (score -1):

This's full script, I would like to make it working on every internal link.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate( {
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-40
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
      window.location.hash = target;
    } );
  } );
} );
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?